# trigger function on Button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Jquery code won't trigger function when simulating button click.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="latz-secondItem">
     <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" style="display:   
           block;">Previous</button>
     <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" style="display:  
           block;">Next</button>
</section>
```

**Jquery:**

```
/* link directly to the 2nd slide */
var hashTag = window.location.hash;
if (hashTag != '' && hashTag == '#latz-secondItem') {               
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $('#latz-secondItem').offset().top
        }, 2000);
     },2000);
     $('#latz-secondItem .slick-next').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: You have to set `$(element).on('click' ...` to trigger an `click` event.

Comment: You don't have any functions being executed on click.

Answer (score 0):

Register callback for click event like this

```
$(function(){
    $(".slick-next").on("click", function(){
         // code to be executed on click
    })
})
```